# Php extract array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structure like below.

```
//var_dump($data):
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2" 
    [2]=> string(4) "4=13" 
    [3]=> string(1) "4" 
    [4]=> string(3) "1=4" 
}
```

Here value 1 and 4 has extension. So I need to get those values.

i.e Final output should be

```
$data = array(1,4);
```

Comment: `$data = array_map('intval', array_filter($data, function($value) { return !is_numeric($value); } ));`

Comment: This is not valid php syntax, are the 3rd and 5th values actually strings?

Comment: That array is not valid. Show the real code.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://eval.in/447741)

Comment: This **still** isnt valid php, now it looks like output from `print_r` function. Either paste the actual code from your IDE or show the output of `var_dump($data);`

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "4=13"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "1=4"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array("1", "2", "4=13", "4", "1=4");
$keys = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, "=") !== false) {
        list($key, $_) = explode("=", $value, 2);
        $keys[] = (int) $key;
    }
}
sort($keys);
var_dump($keys); // array(1, 4)
```